# K-means clustering algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, clustering

Here is my implementation of the k-means algorithm in python. I would love to get any feedback on how it could be improved or any logical errors that you may see. I've left off a lot of the boilerplate code like the command line argument parsing, error handling for data read in from CSV file, etc. and just added the meat of the algorithm.

```
import os
import numpy as np

# kmeans clustering algorithm
# data = set of data points
# k = number of clusters
# c = initial list of centroids (if provided)
#
def kmeans(data, k, c):
    centroids = []

    centroids = randomize_centroids(data, centroids, k)  

    old_centroids = [[] for i in range(k)] 

    iterations = 0
    while not (has_converged(centroids, old_centroids, iterations)):
        iterations += 1

        clusters = [[] for i in range(k)]

        # assign data points to clusters
        clusters = euclidean_dist(data, centroids, clusters)

        # recalculate centroids
        index = 0
        for cluster in clusters:
            old_centroids[index] = centroids[index]
            centroids[index] = np.mean(cluster, axis=0).tolist()
            index += 1


    print("The total number of data instances is: " + str(len(data)))
    print("The total number of iterations necessary is: " + str(iterations))
    print("The means of each cluster are: " + str(centroids))
    print("The clusters are as follows:")
    for cluster in clusters:
        print("Cluster with a size of " + str(len(cluster)) + " starts here:")
        print(np.array(cluster).tolist())
        print("Cluster ends here.")

    return

# Calculates euclidean distance between
# a data point and all the available cluster
# centroids.      
def euclidean_dist(data, centroids, clusters):
    for instance in data:  
        # Find which centroid is the closest
        # to the given data point.
        mu_index = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(instance-centroids[i[0]])) \
                            for i in enumerate(centroids)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
        try:
            clusters[mu_index].append(instance)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[mu_index] = [instance]

    # If any cluster is empty then assign one point
    # from data set randomly so as to not have empty
    # clusters and 0 means.        
    for cluster in clusters:
        if not cluster:
            cluster.append(data[np.random.randint(0, len(data), size=1)].flatten().tolist())

    return clusters


# randomize initial centroids
def randomize_centroids(data, centroids, k):
    for cluster in range(0, k):
        centroids.append(data[np.random.randint(0, len(data), size=1)].flatten().tolist())
    return centroids


# check if clusters have converged    
def has_converged(centroids, old_centroids, iterations):
    MAX_ITERATIONS = 1000
    if iterations > MAX_ITERATIONS:
        return True
    return old_centroids == centroids
```

Comment: See [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/61598/11728) and its answer.

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept the answer. Moreover, where is `c` used in your code?

Comment: what is the data type for `data` ? Numpy array or list of lists/tuple of tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid comments that are identical to the code:

```
# check if clusters have converged  <-- Remove this
def has_converged(centroids, old_centroids, iterations):
```

---

```
MAX_ITERATIONS = 1000
```

Constants should be put at the top of the file to be easier to tweak.

---

Separate calculations from IO, your function `kmeans` should return the values and then another function (maybe `pretty_format_k_means`) should create a human readable message.

---

```
# k = number of clusters
# c = initial list of centroids (if provided)
```

Multi-character variable names are allowed, rename your variables (and function arguments) to more meaningful names, and then you can delete the comments.

Comment: I will agree with Caridorc, but renaming `k` in *k-means* will not be such a good idea, I *think*, +1 though!

Answer (score 0):

To expand Caridorc's answer, I would change that:

```
# c = initial list of centroids (if provided)
def kmeans(data, k, c):
```

to:

```
# c = initial list of centroids (if provided)
def kmeans(data, k, c=None):
```

since `c` may not be provided. So I used the [None keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195989/default-values-for-function-parameters-in-python).

*However*, note that in your code, you do not use `c`!