# K-means clustering implemented in Python 3

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, clustering

Here is the classic K-means clustering algorithm implemented in Python 3. My main concern is time/memory efficiency and if there are version specific idioms that I could use to address issues of the former.

```
import numpy as np

class kmeans():
    '''
    Implementation of classical k-means clustering algorithm
    parameters : dataset n x m ndarray of n samples and m features
    n_clusters : number of clusters to assign samples to
    limit : tolerance between successive iterations
    '''
    def __init__(self, dataset, n_clusters, limit):

        self.dataset = dataset
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.limit = limit

        # dictionary to hold each cluster as a list of samples
        self.clusters = {i: [] for i in range(self.n_clusters)}

        # the centroids of each cluster
        self.centroids = np.ndarray((n_clusters, dataset.shape[1]))

        # values of utility function. increases in size  by 1
        # in each iteration
        self.util_func_vals = []

    def assign_to_clusters(self):

        for idx, sample in enumerate(self.dataset):

            distances = []
            # for each sample we compute its distance from every centroid
            for centroid in self.centroids:
                distances.append(np.linalg.norm(sample - centroid))

            # and assign it to the appropriate cluster
            appropriate_cluster = distances.index(min(distances))

            self.clusters[appropriate_cluster].append(sample)

    def calc_utility_function(self):

        total_sum = 0
        # utility function is the sum of intra-cluster distances
        # the goal is to minimize it
        for cluster, samples in self.clusters.items():

            for i in range(len(samples)):

                for j in range(i + 1, len(samples)):

                    total_sum += np.linalg.norm(samples[i] - samples[j])

        return total_sum

    def calc_new_centroids(self):
        # we calculate new centroids by obtaining the centers of each
        #(each) cluster
        centers = np.ndarray(shape=self.centroids.shape)

        for key, samples in self.clusters.items():
            temp_mean = []
            temp_sam = np.array(samples)
            # that is the mean of each feature
            for i in range(self.dataset.shape[1]):
                temp_mean.append(sum(temp_sam[:, i]) / temp_sam.shape[0])
            centers[key] = np.array(temp_mean)

        # the new centroid is the sample in the cluster that is closest
        # to the mean point 
        for i in range(centers.shape[0]):

            distances = [np.linalg.norm(centers[i] - sample)
                     for sample in self.clusters[i]]
            new_centroid = distances.index(min(distances))
            self.centroids[i] = self.clusters[i][new_centroid]

        # clusters dictionary must empty in order to repopulate
        self.clusters = {i: [] for i in range(self.n_clusters)}

    def compute(self):
        # core method that computes the clusters
        # initialize centroids by randomly choosing #n_clusters samples 
        # from dataset 
        self.centroids = self.dataset[np.random.choice(self.dataset.shape[0],
                                                   size=self.n_clusters,
                                                   replace=False), :]
        # apply the first two steps of the algorithm
        self.assign_to_clusters()
        self.util_func_vals.append(self.calc_utility_function())

        self.calc_new_centroids()

        self.assign_to_clusters()
        self.util_func_vals.append(self.calc_utility_function())

        # and continue until the succesive value difference of utility
        # function becomes lower than the user specified limit
        while abs(self.util_func_vals[-1] - self.util_func_vals[-2]) > self.limit:

            self.calc_new_centroids()

            self.assign_to_clusters()

            self.util_func_vals.append(self.calc_utility_function())
```

Here is the code for a demo execution of the algorithm:

```
from kmeans import kmeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np


# put some random samples with different distributions in the plane
# in order to visualize as 3 groups
r1 = np.ndarray(shape=(200, 2))
r2 = np.ndarray(shape=(200, 2))
r3 = np.ndarray(shape=(200, 2))

r1x = 0.7 * np.random.randn(200) + 2
r1y = 0.5 * np.random.randn(200) + 4
r2x = 0.7 * np.random.randn(200) + 2
r2y = 0.5 * np.random.randn(200) + 2
r3x = 0.7 * np.random.randn(200) + 8
r3y = 0.5 * np.random.randn(200) + 6

for i in range(200):
    r1[i] = np.array([r1x[i],r1y[i]])
    r2[i] = np.array([r2x[i],r2y[i]])
    r3[i] = np.array([r3x[i],r3y[i]])

R = np.concatenate((r1,r2,r3),0)

# plot them 
BEFORE = pl.figure(1)
pl.plot(R[:,0],R[:,1],'o')
BEFORE.show()

# apply kmeans clustering
g = kmeans(R,3,0.5)
g.compute()

# and plot the clusters in different colors
AFTER = pl.figure(2)
x = [item[0] for item in g.clusters[0]]
y = [item[1] for item in g.clusters[0]]
pl.plot(x, y, 'co')
x = [item[0] for item in g.clusters[1]]
y = [item[1] for item in g.clusters[1]]
pl.plot(x, y, 'yo')
x = [item[0] for item in g.clusters[2]]
y = [item[1] for item in g.clusters[2]]
pl.plot(x, y, 'mo')
pl.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your question. I fixed the syntax errors directly in the question, which is way better than asking us to fix it ourselves.

Comment: What was wrong with [`scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans)?

Comment: @GarethRees Absolutely nothing. I'm just practicing :-)

Comment: @Sorrop: That's fine, but it's worth mentioning in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

class kmeans():
```

Use a PEP 8 checker such as pycodestyle or flake8. Integrate it into your file editor or IDE, if you're not doing it already. Some violations get missed by those tools. For example, class names should use uppercase, so "KMeans" here.

```
    '''
    Implementation of classical k-means clustering algorithm
    parameters : dataset n x m ndarray of n samples and m features
    n_clusters : number of clusters to assign samples to
    limit : tolerance between successive iterations
    '''
    def __init__(self, dataset, n_clusters, limit):

        self.dataset = dataset
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.limit = limit

        # dictionary to hold each cluster as a list of samples
        self.clusters = {i: [] for i in range(self.n_clusters)}
```

For speed, consider storing the cluster membership information in the dataset.

```
        # the centroids of each cluster
        self.centroids = np.ndarray((n_clusters, dataset.shape[1]))
```

I like that the code is generic enough to handle more than two dimensions.

```
        # values of utility function. increases in size  by 1
        # in each iteration
        self.util_func_vals = []
```

`util_func_vals` is not really descriptive. First, we [usually describe this as the objective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), not as an "utility function". And `vals` does not add value to the name. Consider using a name such as `objective_history`. Not great, but better. Finding great names is hard, but it's worth it.

```
    def assign_to_clusters(self):

        for idx, sample in enumerate(self.dataset):
```

A for loop! This is among the first thing you should try to eliminate to make your code faster. This is called vectorizing your code. You can probably make most operations on the whole `self.dataset` at once. See this [awesome k-means answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63245/11227) to see how it could be done.

```
            distances = []
            # for each sample we compute its distance from every centroid
            for centroid in self.centroids:
                distances.append(np.linalg.norm(sample - centroid))
```

For speed, don't use linalg.norm, because it does an extra square root that you don't need. Indeed sqrt(a) > sqrt(b) is equivalent to a > b, so you don't need the square root. However, I tried to replace linalg.norm with a version without square roots, and it was slower. Always profile your code before trying to optimize it.

```
    def calc_utility_function(self):

        total_sum = 0
        # utility function is the sum of intra-cluster distances
        # the goal is to minimize it
        for cluster, samples in self.clusters.items():

            for i in range(len(samples)):

                for j in range(i + 1, len(samples)):

                    total_sum += np.linalg.norm(samples[i] - samples[j])

        return total_sum
```

I profiled your code using cProfile and gprof2dot, and this takes 85% of the time.

[image: Profiling]

85%! But it only serves to know when to stop, this should not be the most expensive function. And indeed, there's a mistake. You're computing the distance between all points in a given cluster, which is O(n^2), while you only need to compute the distance for all points to the centroid, which is O(n), much much faster. Here's the new function:

```
def calc_utility_function(self):
    total_sum = 0
    for cluster, samples in self.clusters.items():
        centroid = self.centroids[cluster]
        for i in range(len(samples)):
            total_sum += np.linalg.norm(samples[i] - centroid)

    return total_sum
```

If it took 1s for 100 samples, it will now take about 4s for 400 samples. But with your code it would have taken 16s. For 200 samples, it's a 10x improvement. The `calc_utility_function` optimization was so effective that most of the time is spent initializing the code. I went to 2000 samples and profiled again:

[image: Profiling again]

The function that was previously taking 85% of the time is now taking 15% of the time.

```
    def calc_new_centroids(self):
        # we calculate new centroids by obtaining the centers of each
        # (each) cluster
```

Not much to say here, but try to see if this can be vectorized.

```
        # clusters dictionary must empty in order to repopulate
        self.clusters = {i: [] for i in range(self.n_clusters)}
```

Don't do this here, but do it at the beginning of the function. This way, it's easy to access the dictionary outside of the function since there's no side effect.

```
    def compute(self):
        # core method that computes the clusters
        # initialize centroids by randomly choosing #n_clusters samples 
        # from dataset 
        self.centroids = self.dataset[np.random.choice(self.dataset.shape[0],
                                                   size=self.n_clusters,
                                                   replace=False), :]

        # apply the first two steps of the algorithm
        self.assign_to_clusters()
        self.util_func_vals.append(self.calc_utility_function())

        self.calc_new_centroids()

        self.assign_to_clusters()
        self.util_func_vals.append(self.calc_utility_function())
```

This is ugly because you're repeating yourself. If you define self.utils_func_vals to [math.inf], then you can put everything in the loop (see below).

```
        # and continue until the succesive value difference of utility
        # function becomes lower than the user specified limit
        while abs(self.util_func_vals[-1] - self.util_func_vals[-2]) > self.limit:
```

Use [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose): `math.isclose(self.util_func_vals[-1], self.util_func_vals[-2], abs_tol=limit)`.

Here's the new loop:

```
    converged = False
    while not converged:
        self.assign_to_clusters()
        self.calc_new_centroids()
        self.util_func_vals.append(self.calc_utility_function())
        converged = math.isclose(
            self.util_func_vals[-1],
            self.util_func_vals[-2],
            abs_tol=self.limit)
```

Much cleaner, and there's no messy initialization.

And of course, if you really want speed, use the implementation from scipy as mentioned by @GarethRees.

Comment: "I tried to replace `numpy.linalg.norm` with a version without square roots, and it was slower" — did you try [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) with `metric='sqeuclidean'`? See for example the code at the end of [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63245/11728).

Comment: That's an awesome answer :) Good job. I'd also recommend `scipy` when talking about speed.

Comment: @GarethRees cdist expects an ndarray, so I doubt I would get any benefit without vectorizing first.

Comment: What a great answer! Thank you for your time! I'm using sublime 3 with anaconda package which has PEP8 compliance auto check but missed the naming conventions. Also +1 for code vectorization which is something i have to dig into i guess.