# K-Means clustering in Python2

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, reinventing-the-wheel, clustering

I've implemented the **K-Means** clustering algorithm in Python2, and I wanted to know what remarks you guys could make regarding my code. I've included a small test set with 2D-vectors and 2 classes, but it works with higher dimensions and more classes. Here, it should sort all the elements starting with the same letters in the same classes (except *ak*, with is quite in between).

What I'm interested in:

- Did I do something *unpythonic*?
- Are there unclear or unnecessary parts?
- What changes could drastically improve the code's performance?

---

```
from __future__ import print_function
from operator import add, sub
from _collections import defaultdict
import random as rd
import math


class Element:
    def __init__(self, idf, data, cls='ukn'):
        self.idf = idf
        self.data = data
        self.cls = cls

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s -> %s' % (str(self.idf), str(self.data), str(self.cls))

    def eucl_dist_to(self, other):
        diff = map(sub, self.data, other.data)
        norm2 = math.sqrt(sum([math.pow(coord, 2) for coord in diff]))
        return norm2


def main():
    test_data_tuple = [('aa', 1, 7), ('ab', 1, 8), ('ac', 1, 9), ('ba', 2, 1), ('bb', 2, 3), ('ad', 2, 8), ('ae', 2, 9),
                   ('bc', 3, 2), ('bd', 3, 4), ('af', 3, 7), ('be', 4, 2), ('bf', 4, 3), ('ag', 4, 8),
                   ('bg', 5, 1), ('bh', 5, 3), ('ah', 5, 6), ('bi', 6, 2), ('bj', 6, 4), ('ai', 6, 6), ('aj', 6, 7),
                   ('bk', 7, 0), ('bl', 7, 2), ('bm', 7, 3), ('ak', 7, 5)]
    test_data_elt = list()
    for t in test_data_tuple:
        test_data_elt.append(Element(t[0], tuple(t[1:])))
    # test_data_elt.sort(key=lambda e: e.idf)
    results = k_means(test_data_elt, 2, 5)


def k_means(elts, nb_classes, nb_steps):
    k = nb_classes
    #init
    centroids = list()
    cls_content = defaultdict(list)
    for cls_nb in range(k):
        cls_name = 'class_'+str(cls_nb)
        centroids.append(Element(cls_name, rd.choice(elts).data, cls='centroid'))
        cls_content[cls_name] = list()

    for itr in range(nb_steps):
        # assign
        cls_content.clear()
        for elt in elts:
            min_dist = float('inf')
            for c in centroids:
                dist = c.eucl_dist_to(elt)
                if dist < min_dist:
                    min_dist = dist
                    best_class = c.idf
            cls_content[best_class].append(elt)
            elt.cls = best_class
        # adjust
        for c in centroids:
            elts_in = list(cls_content[c.idf])
            if len(elts_in) == 0:
                sum_elts_data = 0
            else:
                sum_elts_data = list(elts_in[0].data)
                for elt in elts_in[1:]:
                    sum_elts_data = map(add, sum_elts_data, elt.data)
                sum_elts_data[:] = [e / float(len(elts_in)) for e in sum_elts_data]
                c.data = tuple(sum_elts_data)
        print('\nIteration %d' % itr)
        for c in centroids:
            cls_name = c.idf
            print('\n'+str(c))
            for e in cls_content[cls_name]:
                print(e)
    return cls_content


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did you consider using [`scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html)?

Comment: Well, the point was to code the thing myself, I sure assumed that really good implementations already existed, I just wanted to have a go on my own :) Although I didn't know this one, thanks for having linked it!

Comment: That's fine, I just wanted to check. (Take a look at [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63245/11728) for some implementation ideas.)

Answer (score 2):

> something unpythonic?

Consider using plural identifiers: `test_data_tuples`, `test_data_elts`. Later, for example, you use a perfectly lovely `for elt in elts:` idiom.

In Element `__init__`, I wouldn't mind seeing cls='unknown' spelled out, but I am *really* missing a docstring that explains what the heck `idf` stands for. Also, as near as I can tell, `data` really is a `coord`, e.g. `(x, y)`.

Kudos on `k = nb_classes`. I feel you did a good job of making the public API very clear, and then within the body `k` is conventional.

I can't say I'm a fan of `import random as rd`. It needlessly obscured the fairly obvious meaning of `rd.choice(elts).data`.

The `for itr ...` loop exhibits admirable clarity.

Testing `if len(elts_in) == 0:`, plus the `map`, seems like it's maybe a bit clunky. I'm just not understanding why empty is a special case, perhaps we could use `sum` and `lambda`, or a helper function? It seems like we could always find something sensible to assign to `c.data`, even in the empty case. Or maybe what I'm really looking for is an `if` that rapidly moves on to a `continue`.

The `print('\n'+str(c))` is not very pythonic. I'd prefer `print('\n%s' % c)`. Ok, that's the last of the tiny nits I will pick.

Overall, it looks like fairly solid code.

> changes could drastically improve the code's performance?

Sorry, don't see anything obvious that would help.